# Python 2.6 - Import CSV Issue

Tags: python, csv, python-import

I know this is basic but I'm struggling with reading a csv file and haven't come across any postings similar to help rectify it.

This is my code:

```
f = open('test.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

I don't get an error message it's just looking for more steps - I tried f.close() and then get an error.

Here's a sample of the file I'm trying to import:

```
Group Total
1       20
1       30
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify your issue, are you looking to close the file?

Comment: The file you are trying to import doesn't look like a CSV file to me.

Comment: As @Pablo suggested, it's not a csv file. Csv file should be comma-seperated.

Comment: I'm trying to load the csv file and print its contents to view it and go from there.  I get the invalid syntax when I use te close function - wasn't sure if that's what I needed to view since it's expected more stmts when I print row

Comment: Your file is a CSV file, but it uses a different delimiter. You should pass the `delimiter` option to the csv reader if the file is single-space- or TAB-separated, or, better, use `pandas.read_table()` which is smart enough to read files like yours.

Comment: Ah ok. I can read it into pandas but was trying to load it this way instead since want to work with the itertools after but I guess I could do that and translate the dataframe

Comment: Thank you - got it. Added the delimiter and it worked